# swift 5 How to set icon App in Switch Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift5, hig

How to set the app icon in the app switcher screen?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the required App Icon assets.
Please refer to [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/) documentation:

> > Every app must supply small icons for use on the Home screen and throughout the system once your app is installed, as well as a larger icon for display in the App Store.

So in your `Images.assets` just put all required app icon assets and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

That being said, this isn't a problem you can fix. This is a bug in Apple's code not yours.

This will take effect after the second launch!

```js
do {
   try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: NSHomeDirectory()+"/Library/SplashBoard")
} catch {
   print("Failed to delete launch screen cache: \(error)")
}
```